# Changing MenuBar style from Panel through uiBinder - GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt, web

I have a uiBinder Setup like this:

```
<ui:style field="localStyle">
    .action {
        background-color: #529412;
        height: 28px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .action > table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .action a {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</ui:style>
    <g:FlowPanel>
        <g:SimplePanel ui:field='action' styleName='{localStyle.action}'>
            <g:HorizontalPanel>
                <g:Cell verticalAlignment="MIDDLE" horizontalAlignment="LEFT">
                    <g:SimplePanel ui:field='navigations' styleName='{localStyle.navigations}'></g:SimplePanel>
                </g:Cell>
                <g:Cell verticalAlignment="MIDDLE" horizontalAlignment="RIGHT">
                    <g:SimplePanel ui:field='actions' styleName='{localStyle.actions}'></g:SimplePanel>
                </g:Cell>
            </g:HorizontalPanel>
        </g:SimplePanel>
        <g:SimplePanel ui:field='content'>

        </g:SimplePanel>
    </g:FlowPanel>
```

But I set up a MenuBar in that uifield:action through code something like :

```
   private MenuBar createMenuBar(){
        MenuBar menuButton = new MenuBar();
        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar(true);


        mb.addItem(getAboutMenuItem());
        mb.addItem(getLogoutMenuItem());

        return menuButton;
    }
```

When I want to style the MenuBar's colour,nHow would i go about this ... I've tried like

```
.actions MenuBar {
background-color: #eee;
}
```

But it doesn't like that. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access GWT widgets via class name in the CSS.

You have to create a class name in your Ui:Binder css like

```
.menuBar {/* STYLE */}
```

Then inject the style into your Java class as described in the official documentation:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access

Then you can access the style in your Java class and do

```
mb.addStyleName(css.menuBar);
```

Comment: So do like mb.addStyleName("localStyle.action"); ? ... I'm a little confused with the injection, where do I use the `void setEnabled(boolean enabled)` function

Comment: You have to put the css from your Ui:Binder into your java class via an interface, as described in the documentation:

Comment: The "setEnabled" in the documentation is only part of the example and has nothing to do with the styling itself

Comment: Thanks I got it. Would you happen to know how to edit the css, so when i hover over the menuBar with my mouse the background of the menuBar won't change color, but instead make the test to be underlined ?

Comment: Edit the .menuBar:hover { /* STYLE */ } to avoid the background-color change on mouse over. In your java class you can addMouseOverHandler(...) and addMouseOutHandler(...) to the mb and then style something else inside the callback.